# Getting errors while building a PDF QA with OPEN AI & Langchain

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, py-langchain, openaiembeddings

I am trying to use Langchain & AI. So, I have installed all the libraries and tried to write the below code with Langchain documentation. But I seem to face some errors which I am not able to resolve.

Here is my code:

```
import os
from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain.embeddings import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA

os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY'] = 'OPenAi key'

persist_directory = "./storage"
loader = PyPDFLoader("sodapdf-converted.pdf")
documents = loader.load()

documents = loader.load()

text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=512, chunk_overlap=10)
texts = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)

embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
vectordb = Chroma.from_documents(documents=texts, 
                                 embedding=embeddings,
                                 persist_directory=persist_directory)
vectordb.persist()

retriever = vectordb.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"k": 3})
llm = ChatOpenAI(model_name='gpt-4')

qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=llm, chain_type="stuff", retriever=retriever)

while True:
        user_input = input("Enter a query: ")
        if user_input == "exit":
            break

        query = f"###Prompt {user_input}"
        try:
            llm_response = qa(query)
            print(llm_response["result"])
        except Exception as err:
            print('Exception occurred. Please try again', str(err))
```

And I am getting the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ansha\OneDrive\Documents\Python\HOA Search\Langchain\test.py", line 21, in <module>
    vectordb = Chroma.from_documents(documents=texts,
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ansha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\langchain\vectorstores\chroma.py", line 564, in from_documents
    return cls.from_texts(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ansha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\langchain\vectorstores\chroma.py", line 528, in from_texts
    chroma_collection.add_texts(texts=texts, metadatas=metadatas, ids=ids)
  File "C:\Users\ansha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\langchain\vectorstores\chroma.py", line 166, in add_texts
    embeddings = self._embedding_function.embed_documents(list(texts))
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ansha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\langchain\embeddings\openai.py", line 478, in embed_documents
    return self._get_len_safe_embeddings(texts, engine=self.deployment)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ansha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\langchain\embeddings\openai.py", line 328, in _get_len_safe_embeddings
    response = embed_with_retry(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ansha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\langchain\embeddings\openai.py", line 107, in embed_with_retry
    return _embed_with_retry(**kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ansha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tenacity\__init__.py", line 289, in wrapped_f
    return self(f, *args, **kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ansha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tenacity\__init__.py", line 379, in __call__
    do = self.iter(retry_state=retry_state)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ansha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tenacity\__init__.py", line 314, in iter
    return fut.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ansha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 449, in result
    return self.__get_result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ansha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 401, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Users\ansha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tenacity\__init__.py", line 382, in __call__
    result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ansha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\langchain\embeddings\openai.py", line 104, in _embed_with_retry
    response = embeddings.client.create(**kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ansha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openai\api_resources\embedding.py", line 33, in create
    response = super().create(*args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ansha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openai\api_resources\abstract\engine_api_resource.py", line 153, in create
    response, _, api_key = requestor.request(
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ansha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openai\api_requestor.py", line 298, in request
    resp, got_stream = self._interpret_response(result, stream)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ansha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openai\api_requestor.py", line 700, in _interpret_response
    self._interpret_response_line(
  File "C:\Users\ansha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openai\api_requestor.py", line 763, in _interpret_response_line
    raise self.handle_error_response(
openai.error.AuthenticationError: Incorrect API key provided: cjbZWnFC************************************xYfa. You can find your API key at https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys.
```

Please ignore the Incorrect API Key error.

Comment: So you are asking us about the incorrect API key error and at the same time you are telling us to ignore the incorrect API key error. What do you want from us?